# Load CSS into a PHP file

Tags: php, html, css

everybody. I am following a tutorial to create a register and login system, I am doing it for the first time. I am not being able to style the HTML form that is in the PHP file. I just have one folder with 6 files (error.php, index.php, login.php, register.php, server.php, style.css)
So far I have just wrote code in the register.php and style.css files.
And I get this messages from the console in the register.php file:
1- "The stylesheet http://localhost/registration/register.php/style.css was loaded as CSS even though its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”."

2- "Ruleset ignored due to bad selector."

What's wrong? I am working with XAMPP

This is the code:

register.php:

```
<?php
include('server.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration system PHP and MySQL</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <h2>Register</h2>
</div>

<form method="post" action="register.php">
<?php
include('errors.php');
?>
 <div class="input-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php
echo $username;
?>">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php
echo $email;
?>">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_1">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>Confirm password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_2">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user">Register</button>
  </div>
  <p>
      Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
  </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
    * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-size: 120%;
  background: #F8F8FF;
}

.header {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px auto 0px;
  color: white;
  background: #5F9EA0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}
form, .content {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.input-group {
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.input-group label {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 3px;
}
.input-group input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 93%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background: #5F9EA0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.error {
  width: 92%; 
  margin: 0px auto; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #a94442; 
  color: #a94442; 
  background: #f2dede; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  text-align: left;
}
.success {
  color: #3c763d; 
  background: #dff0d8; 
  border: 1px solid #3c763d;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `href="style.css"` with `href="./style.css"`, you must point css to same directory as your php files

Comment: Van Tho, same result.

Comment: How about `href="/registration/style.css"`

Comment: Van Tho, that worked, thank you so much. Why this worked?

Comment: Because your css file is in the folder registration, not `registration/register.php/style.css`, normally ./style.css will works, but this case you may need to use `/registration/style.css`

Comment: I get it, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

There two ways that you can try

Replace your line

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

With

1: Point to current directory

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">`

2: Point from root directory

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/registration/style.css">`

Because your css file is in the folder `/registration/`, not `/registration/register.php/`